# Why would one buy a Bitcoin future or perpetual as opposed to actual Bitcoin via the spot market?

Tags: market, futures

I often hear that the futures and perpetual markets for bitcoin help its price discovery. So this must mean that these markets for bitcoin are quite active.

But would people want exposure to bitcoin through futures or perpetuals when they can just buy the asset directly using a spot market?